# Spring security does not allow access through https

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I tried to access external static content which i am able to access through HTTP but not HTTPS. Configuration done as below:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/file/**")
          .addResourceLocations("file:///C:/Work/Testing/" );
}

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/file/**").permitAll()

web.ignoring().antMatchers("/file/**");
```

Access:

```
http://localhost:8080/file/hello.html -> Can see hello world page
https://localhost:8080/file/hello.html -> got 404 error
```

May I know how can I access it through HTTPS. Thank you in advance if you guys can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable ssl and setup ssl certs for your local tomcat/any server that you are using  then only you can access https://localhost .
Read the below blog

https://certsimple.com/blog/localhost-ssl-fix .